Why is Cohen's $h$ useful to compare proportions when the risk difference is so interpretable?
Why is Cohen's $h$ useful to compare proportions when the risk difference is so interpretable?
I think it has to do with standardizing the comparison across different magnitudes of proportions (e.g., $p_{1}-p_{2}$ when $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ are each close to $0$ vs. close to $0.5$ vs. close to $1$).
But I'm having hard time formalizing that in my head.

Cohen's $h$ is more useful than risk difference when conducting power analysis for designing a study. Indeed, the same risk difference has not the same degree of "detectability", depending on the values of the proportions: for the same risk difference, it's harder for a test to detect differences when proportions are closer to $0.5$. The original purpose of Cohen's $h$ is to get around this problem when conducting power analysis. See Cohen, 1988, section 6.2, pp. 180-181:

If we were to define $j = P_1 - P_2$ , and try to use $j$ as our ES, we would soon discover that the detectability of some given value of $j$, under given fixed conditions of $a$ and $n$, would not be constant, but would vary depending upon where along the scale of $P$ between zero and one the value $j$ occurred.
[...]
As was the case with $r$, a nonlinear transformation of $P$ provides a solution to the problem. When $P$'s are transformed by the relationship
$\phi = 2 \arcsin\sqrt{P}$
equal differences between $\phi$'s are equally detectable.

For instance it's more difficult to detect a difference when the true proportions in the population are $p_1=0.50$ and $p_2=0.45$, than proportions such as $p_1=0.25$ and $p_2=0.20$. In other words, in the former case, you'll need a larger sample size to detect the difference, despite the risk difference being the same in the latter case.
Here's an example in R, where we simulate 10,000 random samples, to compare proportions coming from two different binomial distributions (where $p_1=0.25$ and $p_2=0.20$), with a sample size of $n=1500$ for each group. Let's see how many of these simulations get a p-value $< 0.05$:
set.seed(0)
p1    = 0.25
p2    = 0.20
alpha = 0.05
n     = 1500
results = c()
for(i in 1:10000){
  group1  = rbinom(n=1, size=n, prob = p1)
  group2  = rbinom(n=1, size=n, prob = p2)
  res     = prop.test(x=c(group1, group2), n=c(n, n), correct=FALSE)
  results = c(results, res$p.value)
}
mean(results<alpha)  # [1] 0.9068

Here, we get a power of $0.9068$ for an alpha level of $0.05$. But if we re-run the same code, just changing the proportions to $p_1=0.5$ and $p_2=0.45$, the power drops to about $0.79$. Here's a power curve, showing how power changes as $p1$ varies between $0$ and $1$, while keeping everything else constant, including the risk difference:

So we can't just use the risk difference in the context of power analysis. To mitigate the issue, we can apply an arcsine transformation as defined by Cohen to determine a relevant effect size, which gives Cohen's $h$:
$$h=2\arcsin\sqrt{p_1}-2\arcsin\sqrt{p_2}.$$
You see that with $p_1=0.50$ and $p_2=0.45$, you get an effect size $h=0.1001674$, while with $p_1=0.25$ and $p_2=0.20$, $h=0.1199023$. So $h$ includes information that is not available in the risk difference alone.
How to use this effect size $h$ in the context of power analysis?
Page 548 and 549 of his book, Cohen gives formulas to determine power or required sample size, using $h$. For instance, p. 549, he gives the following formula for the required sample size per group:
$$n = 2\left( \frac{z_{1-\alpha} + z_{1-\beta}}{h}\right)^{2}  $$
with:

$z$ representing the normal quantile function (e.g. ?qnormin R),
$\alpha$ being the significance level,
$1-\beta$ the statistical power,
and $h$ being Cohen's $h$.

Software for power analysis will do all the calculations for you, so you don't bother too much with the computational details. If you're interested in the implementation of those formulas, you can refer to the source code of the many existing open-source software or libraries for power analysis.
As a end user, how to plug $h$ in those software? If may depend on the software you're using. Some software might calculate the arcsine transformation under the hood for you, while others might not, so you should refer to the documentation of the software you're using. The important thing to remember is that power may vary a lot depending on the specific proportions: don't assume that a given sample size will give you the same statistical power for detecting identical risk differences, no matter the proportions.
Here is an example in R, that shows how to determine the required sample size with the pwr library, to get a power of $0.9$ with an alpha level of $0.05$ for a two-sided test, using the arcsine transformation (calculated with the ?ES.h function):
library(pwr)
sampsize.prop.test = function(p1, p2){
  h = ES.h(p1, p2)
  n = ceiling(pwr.2p.test(h=h, sig.level=0.05, power=0.9, alternative="two.sided")$n)
  return(n)
}
sampsize.prop.test(p1=0.25, p2=0.20)  # [1] 1462
sampsize.prop.test(p1=0.50, p2=0.45)  # [1] 2095

If we want a power of $0.9$, we will need a sample size of $n=1462$ per group if the true proportions in the population are $p_1=0.25$ and $p_2=0.20$. On the other hand, we'll need a sample size of $n=2095$ per group if the true proportions are $p_1=0.50$ and $p_2=0.45$ in the population.
To get a more visual idea of what is happening, here is a graph showing the required sample size per group, as a function of $p_1$, everything else being equal (power=$0.9$, alpha=$0.05$, risk difference=$0.05$):

You see that depending on the assumptions you make about $p1$, the required sample may increase substantially, so you need more information than just the risk difference alone to design a study properly.
--
Reference
Cohen, J. (1988). Statistical Power Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences (2nd ed.). Routledge. https://doi.org/10.4324/9780203771587.

Excellent answer!  Comprehensive & authoritative.  I will try to remember to add a bounty to this thread in a couple days.

@gung-ReinstateMonica Thanks! It was not entirely comprehensive, as I did not mention how exactly $h$ is used when computing power. I just added some details about  that, from what Jacob Cohen explains in his book. Hopefully now it should be a bit more comprehensive. In case some people are interested in more details about the power calculation for the difference between proportions, it may be relevant to ask a different question, or refer to Cohen's book or to the source code of power analysis software.

Hey @J-J-J, a quick tip: if you are using the display mode $$ $$, try to include the punctuation mark within it, otherwise it would make an undesirable indentation effect. Also, I have changed the reference to Routledge's rather than the Amazon link (and +1 already when I first edited few days ago :-)).

@User1865345 Thanks, duly noted! No problem about the reference, it's probably better this way.
